# How do i make the border full color (gray) instead of (half/half) css/html?

Tags: html, css

i am a newbie that tries to learn HTML + CSS

I would like this border to be in full gray color and as we can see its half / half - i do not understand why, thanks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWBkV.png)

my console and image below:

Comment: reset `border-style` to `solid` , buttons have an `outset` style set by default, that's why it seems a lighter and darker color , this is to simulate sort of a shadow for a raising effect of the button.

Answer (score 0):

It might inherit from parent div, please add !important; to force apply css.
Otherwide you can using development tools to check it (Tab Styles and Computed)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i am using visual studio code and my "window of program" looks different,  maybe im just too new to understand your answer, but thank you sir, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Use an universal property [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)

```css
.download-button {
    height: 50px;
    width: 140px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    color: grey;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="download-button">Download</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Vladislav, it works, have a nice day !